# VMware event hooks in .NET

Tags: .net, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm developing an in-house .NET application that will be run on a VM (with VMware), and want to know if there's a way to get notifications from VM system events (like suspending, resumed, etc.)

Anyone know of a convenient way to do that?  The virtual machine has VMware Tools installed, does that provide a .NET API for hooking events?

**EDIT:** In particular, I'm interested in when the system has just resumed.  I assumed that this doesn't correspond to any "regular" Windows system event (after all, the whole point of suspending and resuming a VM is that Windows has no idea what happened).  Am I mistaken?  Will that trigger an event?

**EDIT 2:** I wrote this quick console app to hook all the System Events I could think of, and get nothing when I suspend/resume:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

    SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Display settings changed");
    SystemEvents.EventsThreadShutdown += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Events thread shutdown");
    SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Power mode changed");
    SystemEvents.SessionEnding += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Session ending");
    SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Session switch");
    SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanging += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("User preference changing");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the standard windows events?

Comment: I've given up looking for a hook and solved this with a timer, but if anyone has a better solution, I'd be happy to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I've given up on looking for an easy .NET hook for this, but if someone else stumbles on this and wants to know how I solved it:

I have a timer in my app that fires regularly (every 10 seconds), and compares the current time to the last time.  If the time is appreciably longer than 10 seconds, I assume that the computer has either been asleep or suspended, and refresh my app as needed.

A little hacky, but the timer adds nothing to the program's CPU or memory usage, so I figure it's not horrible.

Answer (score 2):

are there any vmware-specific events you'd be listening for?  Otherwise it sounds like you'd be better off listening for those events from Windows

---

Take a look at [WM_POWERBROADCAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373247(VS.85).aspx) -- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.RegisterPowerSettingNotification

Comment: I don't know which system events would correspond to a "resume"... see edit.

Comment: if you can detect it entering standby then you can set some sort of flag that the application is in standby--if the application starts running and sees it's in standby then it can infer that it must have just resumed

Comment: That would work if it went into standby, but suspending a VM isn't the same as the standby power mode.

Comment: haven't found anything promising in the documentation--detecting a Suspend operating might not be possible (would you want to delay the Suspend if your application took a while to complete?)... so it's also possible there isn't any notification to the guest that it's been resumed